# How to make that a WPF visual item stretches in width, but shows the horizontal scrollbar at a minimum width?

Tags: wpf, scrollviewer

I want this behavior:

- Have an visual item (for example a Grid) inside a ScrollViewer
- This item has a MinimunWidth and the scroll viewer has horizontal scroll bar enabled
- I want the item to be stretched in width (the width of the container), but when this item gets a minimun width the horizontal scrollbar is showed, and then when the container gives more width than the item's minimun width the item will stretch again.

Actual behavior:

The problem here is that when the horizontal scroll bar is showed the visual item does not stretch any more, and remains at the same width disregarding it container size. Please, anyone knows how to change this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example demonstrates the behavior you want:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <Grid MinWidth="200" MinHeight="200" Background="Red" />
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

Comment: You are right, this code works as I want, the problem was that I had a more complex escenarion and didn't work properly, but this post helps to solve it, thanks